# Change baseurl in Jekyll site destroy the CSS

Tags: github, jekyll, github-pages

I am a new user of Jekyll and not familiar with web technologies. I create my blog with theses commands. Adding articles and publish them works perfectly. However, when I change the `baseurl` parameter in the `_config.yml` broke the CSS website.
[CSS Broken by baseurl modifications](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SOTD5.png)

This is the commands I execute :

```
git clone mypseudo.github.io (empty repository)
jekyll new mypseudo.github.io
cd mypseudo.github.io
bundle exec jekyll serve
git add --all
git commit -m "Initial commit"
git push origin master
```

At this step, the blog is perfect. Now I add my files

```
git add --all
git commit -m "Adding articles"
git push origin master
```

At this step, blog is perfect

Modification of the `_config.yml`. Change of the value `baseurl: ""` to `baseurl: "/blog"` :

```
git add _config.yml
git commit -m "Modification of the base URL"
git push origin master
```

At this step. My blog is broken. Why it's not automatically managed. How can I fix it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your site is hosted at **mypseudo.github.io**, you must have `baseurl: ""` in your config.

If you want to host your site at **mypseudo.github.io/blog**, you need to version your code in a **"blog"** repository, and then you set your `baseurl:"/blog"` to instruct Jekyll to generate valid urls for your ressources.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. So if I want to create a **static website for my CV** and a **separate blog** part I should create the static site in **mypseudo.github.io** and the blog in an other repository called **blog** ?

Comment: This can be a new question on SO. But the short answer is that you can use one repo (mypseudo.github.io) and put all your posts in a **/blog/_posts/** folder, they will have urls of the form mypseudo.github.io/blog/YYYY/MM/DD/post-title/.